# My app is getting crash without any errors if I use onClickListener in ParkActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in Android Development and I have one doubt, How to pass from 2nd Activity into 3rd Activity

```
From MainActivity



    TextView parkText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.park);
            parkText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),ParkActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

From ParkActivity

    public class ParkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.place_list);
    
           final ArrayList<Places> parkPlaceList = new ArrayList<Places>();
            parkPlaceList.add(new Places("TowerPark",R.mipmap.chennai_hdpi));
            parkPlaceList.add(new Places("TowerPark",R.mipmap.chennai_hdpi));
            parkPlaceList.add(new Places("TowerPark",R.mipmap.chennai_hdpi));
            parkPlaceList.add(new Places("TowerPark",R.mipmap.chennai_hdpi));
            parkPlaceList.add(new Places("TowerPark",R.mipmap.chennai_hdpi));
            parkPlaceList.add(new Places("TowerPark",R.mipmap.chennai_hdpi));
            parkPlaceList.add(new Places("TowerPark",R.mipmap.chennai_hdpi));
    
            PlaceAdapter itemsAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(this,parkPlaceList);
            ListView placeList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            placeList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    
    
    
        }
    }

From Places

package com.example.chennaitourapp;
public class Places {


    private String mtextview;
     private int mimageResourceId;

     public Places(String textView, int imageResourceId){
         mtextview = textView;
         mimageResourceId = imageResourceId;
     }
    public String getMtextview() {
        return mtextview;
    }

    public int getMimageResourceId() {
        return mimageResourceId;
    }
}

From PlaceAdapter

public class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {
    public PlaceAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Places>parkPlacelist) {
        super(context, 0,parkPlacelist);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.imagepname,parent,false);
        }
      Places placeListPosition = getItem(position);

        TextView placesName = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        placesName.setText(placeListPosition.getMtextview());

        ImageView placesImage = (ImageView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        placesImage.setImageResource(placeListPosition.getMimageResourceId());





        return listItemView;
```

Now I have to pass from ParkActivity To ParkActivity2 and I created another Activity called ParkActivity2

If I touch or click textview from ParkActivity I need to go to ParkActivity and I know I have to use onClickListener which I already done in MainActivity but I need to know where I have to write that code

Actually I wrote that code in ParkActivity but my app is getting crashed without any errors.

Comment: if i touch or click textview from ParkActivity i need to go to ParkActivity2

Comment: You declared your ParkActivity2 in your Manifest?

Comment: You created new activity manually? If yes then add your activity name in your manifest. like: <activity android:name="ActivtyName2" ></activity>

Comment: You must use clickListener on the adapter. But the error can be something unrelated, probably manifest error as the other users tell you.

Comment: Thanks guys,I got it

Answer (score 1):

In ParkActivity set **onItemClickListener** in your listView (which is **placeList** in your case) after setting the adapter.

```
placeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //go to ParkActivity2
                startActivity(new Intent(context,ParkActivity2.class));
            }
        });
```

Don't forget to add your Activity in Manifest, if you added it manually.

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote the answer if it worked for you, 
Thank you.